# jquery .getJSON output all data .each

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I'm exporting my php as jsonp and then calling a js file which loads in the data.

I'm getting the output of only the last data object.  I would like to loop through the action data and have all of them output into the **<li>data.action</li>** format.  If anyone can help figure how to do this thank you so much.

JSONP

```
({
    "posts": [{
        "action": "go to acting school",
        "action": "go to a beach",
        "action": "go kyacking",
        "action": "go skiing in vermont",
        "action": "sleep in a cave",
        "action": "dress up as favorite celebrity in public",
        "action": "see the cherry blossums in Washington DC",
        "action": "watch all the rocky movies",
        "action": "go sky diving",
        "action": "climb Mount Everest",
        "action": "climb K2",
        "action": "see or participate in war reenactment",
        "action": "spend New Years Eve in Times Square",
        "action": "jump out of a moving plane",
        "action": "jump out of a moving car",
        "action": "try eating a new food"
    }]
})
```

JQUERY

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $.getJSON("http://site.com/lesson.php?count=5&jsoncall=?", function (data) {
         $.each(data.posts, function (i, data) {
             var jsondata = "<li>" + data.action + "</li>";
             $(jsondata).appendTo("ol#results");
         });
     });
     return false;
 });
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have now?

Comment: My output is "try eating a new food". I'm trying to get it to be all of the action items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That isn't proper json. When converted to a javascript object, it will contain:

```
{
    "posts": [{"action": "try eating a new food"}]
}
```

This is what i believe it should be instead:

```
{
    "actions": ["go to acting school","go to a beach","go kyacking","go skiing in vermont","sleep in a cave","dress up as favorite celebrity in public","see the cherry blossums in Washington DC","watch all the rocky movies","go sky diving","climb Mount Everest","climb K2","see or participate in war reenactment","spend New Years Eve in Times Square","jump out of a moving plane","jump out of a moving car","try eating a new food"]
}
```

Obviously this is with no knowledge of what the json actually represents. The thinking behind the change i made is if they are all actions, place them all in one array that is stored in a property called `actions`

You would then output it with:

```
var myStr = "";
$.each(data.actions, function (i, action) {
    myStr += "<li>" + action + "</li>";
});
$("#results").append(myStr);
```

Comment: It is technically valid, it's structure just won't work in the javascript environment. I'll update my answer with what it should be.

Comment: The structure you've created is not JSON, but a javascript object literal.

Comment: @ohgodwhy - no... it is valid json too. (fixed typo, missed a `"action":`)

Answer (score 2):

What you want, is to restructure the JSON so it's valid then things will work well.

[Here's the working jsFiddle showing the example.](http://jsfiddle.net/T9Vdy/)

Answer (score 0):

JSON keys **have to be unique** which is not the case in your code.